# Get parameters and folders depth in a path

Tags: php

How can I take a URL path like this and break it up to

- the params, which in this case would be `param1=1` and `param2=2`
- the end script, like `levelE`
- the middle folders in my script `levelA, levelB, levelC, levelD`

.

```
http://test.com/ levelA/ levelB/ levelC/ levelD/ levelE ? param1=1 & param2=2
```

Another example would be this, where the folder depth is different, and the number of parameters is different:

```
http://test.com/ levelA/ levelB/ levelC/ levelD ? param1=1 & param2=2 & param3=3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to split the URL, and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to split the query string into its components.

The `levelA/levelB/levelC` part is best split using [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode).